# Email signature not appearing in body when mailto used

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Is it possible to have the person who clicks on the link to display their signature?

Currently when I click on the link it opens Outlook but doesn't display the signature. In Outlook signature options are set to display on New messages and Replies/forwards.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": {
                    "operator": "+",
                    "operands": [
                        "mailto:",
                        "@currentField.email",
                        "?subject=Task status&body=Hey, how is your task coming along?.\r\n---\r\n",
                        "@currentField.title",
                        "\r\nClick this link for more info. http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ConferencePrep/Tasks/Prep/DispForm.aspx?ID=",
                        "[$ID]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Seems a workaround is using [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/52924-i-solved-it-mailto-outlook-and-signatures/) is something like this possible straight in the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Using outlook, I was able to get the signature to add automatically by not including body content in the json code. So, the following code would work:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": {
                    "operator": "+",
                    "operands": [
                        "mailto:",
                        "@currentField.email",
                        "?subject=Task status"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was unable to get the mailto to dynamically add a user's signature.

The signature behaviour differs for email clients, if you are using the windows mail app it will insert it automatically. If you are using outlook you can press the signature button to add it on to the mail.